# Set Relations Quick Question

Tags: relations

Can someone please explain how this answer was reached? I know that relation of A is just A * A but wouldn't that just be $4^{2}? $

> Let A = {1, 2, 3, 4}. How many relations are there on a set A?
>
> Solution: $2^{4^2} = 2^{16} = 131,072$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, a [relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_%28mathematics%29) on $A$ is a subset of $A^2$. Since $|A^2|=16$, the number of subsets of $A^2$ is $2^{16}$, which means there are $2^{16}$ relations on $A$.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348775/proving-the-total-number-of-subsets-of-s-is-equal-to-2n/349542#349542) might help you.

Comment: Thanks, the way you explain it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @HermesTrismegistus You're welcome.